# BeamSQL - output file is empty

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

While using BeamSQL in the dataflow pipeline (javacode), after applying SQLTransform.query then getting output as null. In the below example code, trying to read the data from cloud storage and apply the filter using BeamSQL then push the file to cloud storage. In the output of cloud storage file is empty.

```
public static final String HEADER = "artist_credit,position,artist,name,join_phrase";  public static final Schema appSchema =       Schema      .builder()      .addStringField("artist_credit")        .addStringField("position")         .addStringField("artist")       .addStringField("name")         .addStringField("join_phrase")      .build(); public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        PipelineOptionsFactory.register(DefaultOptions.class);  DefaultOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(DefaultOptions.class);   options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);    options.setProject(options.getDataFlowProjectName());   options.setTempLocation(options.getDataFlowProjectTempLocation());  options.setGcpTempLocation(options.getDataFlowProjectTempLocation());   Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

p.apply("read_from_gcs",  TextIO.read().from ("gs://bq_dataflow_testing/files/artist_credit_name.json"))
        .apply("transform_to_row", ParDo.of(new RowParDo())).setRowSchema(appSchema)
        .apply("transform_sql", SqlTransform.query("select `artist_credit`, `position`,`artist`,`name`,`join_phrase` from PCOLLECTION where `position` = '1' "))
        .apply("transform_to_string", ParDo.of(new RowToString()))
        .apply("write_to_gcs", TextIO.write().to("gs://bq_dataflow_testing/file/artist_credit_name.json").withoutSharding());
         p.run().waitUntilFinish();  } 

public static class RowParDo extends DoFn<String, Row> {     @ProcessElement     public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {          if (!c.element().equalsIgnoreCase(HEADER))  {           String[] vals = c.element().split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");            Row appRow
    = Row.withSchema(appSchema)
                        .addValue(vals[0])
                        .addValue(vals[1])
                        .addValue(vals[2])
                        .addValue(vals[3])
                        .addValue(vals[4])
                        .build();           c.output(appRow);       }   } }

    public static class RowToString extends DoFn<Row, String> {     @ProcessElement      public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {          Row e = c.element();        String line = e.getValues()
                    .stream()
                    .map(Object::toString)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));      c.output(line);     } }
```

It would be good if someone help me to fix this issue.

Comment: I would recommend checking the input data to make sure that you have rows with `position` = '1'. You can use a print ParDo to print the output in the job logs and make sure that your filters are working as expected. Also, you should be able to use DirectRunner to test this out.

Comment: Can you share your full code and data sample? Otherwise, it's difficult to tell. If you took `RowParDo` from [this example](https://medium.com/weareservian/exploring-beam-sql-on-google-cloud-platform-b6c77f9b4af4) only a couple fields (position 4 and 6) are parsed, see line 34 [here](https://gist.github.com/polleyg/32af5177c964303c1dff750e6a26a19b#file-beam_sql_all-java)

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I have updated the question with latest code.  This code executes success. However, while debugging it, RowParDo() method got data, where the RowToString() method could not get the record.

Comment: I did a test but it works fine for me: [code](https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/a560b756bc1dc2c1984fa7b58a9b0ad7), so maybe it's something particular to your files (regex?). I would advise to add some logging in `RowParDo`. For reference, I used SDK 2.11.0

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Based on your code I understand that input data type is the problem. If I give input as CSV then it works.